# how to check type of input field in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

Could you please tell me how to check type of input field in react + enzyme ?
I tried like this

```
it("get text of required field", () => {
    wrapper.setProps({
      error: {
          showPassword: true
      }
  });
  expect(wrapper.find(Input).children().hasAttribute('type')).toEqual('text');
  });
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/l2lk4n794l

here is my component

```
<Input
            id="adornment-password"
            type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
            error={error.passwordError || apiError}
            onKeyDown={keyPressHandler}
            value={password}
            classes={{
              root: classes.inputRoot,
              focused: classes.focusedLabel,
              underline: classes.underlineInput
            }}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code sandbox it looks like you are trying to do this:

```
it("get text of required field", () => {
  wrapper.setProps({
    showPassword: true
  });
  expect(wrapper.find('#adornment-password').prop('type')).toEqual("text");  // Success!
});
```

`find` will find the element (in this case by `id`), then you are testing the value of the `type` property and checking to see if the `Input` type changed to `text`.